# How to pass from relative links to absolute links in nokogiri

Tags: ruby, uri, nokogiri

How do you pass from relative links to absolute links:

```
<a href="/foo/ba.pdf">A</a>
<a href="foo/ba.pdf">B</a>
<a href="http://google.com/foo/ba.pdf">A</a>
<a href="#hello">A</a>
```

should transform to

```
<a href="PREFIX/foo/ba.pdf">A</a>
<a href="PREFIX/foo/ba.pdf">B</a>
<a href="http://google.com/foo/ba.pdf">A</a>
<a href="#hello">A</a>
```

where `PREFIX` is string (user defined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the document:

```
<% doc = Nokogiri::HTML(foo)%>
```

where foo is the content you want.

Search links with no scheme and without starting with '/'. So they are relative. With this link append '/' + `PREPEND`

```
<% for link in doc.search('a[href]').select { |l| URI(l['href']).scheme == nil and URI(l['href']).path.start_with?('/') == false }
     link['href'] = '/' + PREPEND + '/' + link['href']
   end
%>
```

Comment: Note that URI.relative? is likely to e better at handling any edge cases than just checking for scheme and host. The above also fails where the  document uses a modified base uri.

Answer (score 0):

With URI:

```
require 'uri'
URI.join('http://google.com/', 'foo')
#<URI::HTTP http://google.com/foo>
```

Comment: I wna to prepend not adding at the end. And just for specific links (see question) not starting with http